# calculating ICC manually versus the performance package

Tags: r, poisson-distribution, glmm, count-data, intraclass-correlation

I reproduced an example I found on Stackexchange, [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173848/intraclass-correlation-with-count-data/173857#173857), and I failed to get the same ICC using the performance::icc package in R. My reproducible example is below. Can someone explain to me why the performance package is giving me a different result. Please note that the performance package is calling insight::get_variance() to calculate the result. As you can see it seems there's a discrepancy in the variance of the residual between calculating it manually versus the package.

```
library(lme4)   # we'll use this package to fit the GLMM
library(performance) 
set.seed(1189)  # this makes the example exactly reproducible

N          = 20                                     # there are 20 people in your study
reps       = 3                                      # w/ 3 observation each
id         = rep(1:N, each=reps)                    # this is the ID indicator
sub.lambda = rnorm(N, mean=1.6, sd=.3)              # here we generate each unit's mean
sub.lambda = rep(sub.lambda, each=reps)             #  & copy them for each observation
y          = rpois(reps*N, lambda=exp(sub.lambda))  # here we generate the counts

mod = glmer(y~(1|id), family=poisson)               # this fits the Poisson GLMM
summary(mod)     


v.RE  = summary(mod)$varcor$id[1];  v.RE   # 0.1066211
v.res = var(resid(mod));            v.res  # 1.141968
ICC   = v.RE/(v.RE+v.res);          ICC    # 0.08539324

performance::icc(mod)               #ICC: 0.338
insight::get_variance(mod)

$var.fixed
[1] 0

$var.random
[1] 0.1066211

$var.residual
[1] 0.2091081

$var.distribution
[1] 0.2091081

$var.dispersion
[1] 0

$var.intercept
       id 
0.1066211
```

Answer (score 1):

The residual variance calculated by the insight package for a Poisson model uses the equation described by Nakagawa and colleagues (2017).

This is: ln(1+1/lambda) where lambda is the mean rate, calculated as exp(intercept)

Here is some code reproducing the residual variance from the insight package and ICC from the performance package:

```
library(lme4)   # we'll use this package to fit the GLMM
library(performance) 
set.seed(1189)  # this makes the example exactly reproducible

N          = 20                                     # there are 20 people in your study
reps       = 3                                      # w/ 3 observation each
id         = rep(1:N, each=reps)                    # this is the ID indicator
sub.lambda = rnorm(N, mean=1.6, sd=.3)              # here we generate each unit's mean
sub.lambda = rep(sub.lambda, each=reps)             #  & copy them for each observation
y          = rpois(reps*N, lambda=exp(sub.lambda))  # here we generate the counts

mod = glmer(y~(1|id), family=poisson)               # this fits the Poisson GLMM
summary(mod)
tidy(mod, exp=T)


v.RE  = summary(mod)$varcor$id[1];  v.RE   # 0.1066211
v.res = var(resid(mod));            v.res  # 1.141968
ICC   = v.RE/(v.RE+v.res);          ICC    # 0.08539324

lambda = (exp(as.numeric(fixef(mod)["(Intercept)"]))) # 4.30
v.res.distribution=log(1+1/lambda) # 0.2091081
ICC_adj = v.RE/(v.RE + v.res.distribution) # 0.338

performance::icc(mod)               #ICC: 0.338
insight::get_variance(mod)
```

**References**

Nakagawa, S., Johnson, P. C. D., & Schielzeth, H. (2017). The coefficient of determination R2 and intra-class correlation coefficient from generalized linear mixed-effects models revisited and expanded. Journal of The Royal Society Interface, 14(134), 20170213. doi:10.1098/rsif.2017.0213

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm not much help but I noticed the same issue using linear mixed models (lmer) - the residual variance you get by using var(resid(mod)) is not the same you get from insight and thus not the same that is used in performance::icc calculations. However for what it's worth, I can see from my lmer model summary that the variance used by performance is correct (or matches the residual variance provided by model summary - the poisson regression summary doesn't seem to provide the residual variance at all). I don't know what's the deal with var(resid) command but based on these observations I'd say performance::icc used the correct residual variance. I hope someone gives you a substantial answer too!